# Make mat-drawer left content sticky

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, sticky

I have a page with scroll that uses mat-drawer component

at the left I have a menu.

I would like that the menu content stay on screen when user scrolls the page

Here's the stackblitz example.

I have tried changing positions to sticky but not working

[mat-drawer-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ybnkff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just fix the sidebar to the left using `position: fixed` then let the content section scroll and leave the sidebar fixed!

styles.scss

```
html,
body {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

component.scss

```
.example-container {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  display: block;
  height: 1000%;
  width: 100%;
}

:host {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  botttom: 0;
}
```

html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="fixed-left"
    >Make this sticky</mat-drawer
  >
  <mat-drawer-content><div>Main content</div></mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ybnkff-aseccc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.css,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you , it's a good solution , the issue is that `mat-drawer` now is getting on top left of the page. I would not position it manually . is it possible to do that with sticky property ?

Comment: @infodev could you share a screenshot of expected output?